# GraphQL arguments on Object in query

Tags: node.js, express, ecmascript-6, graphql, graphql-js

I want to execute a query like this:

```
{
  houses(owner: "Thomas") {
    id
    color
    cars(type: "Sports Car") {
      name
      year
    }
  }
}
```

But this returns an error:

```
"message": "Unknown argument \"type\" on field \"cars\" of type \"House\".",
```

However, I'm able to execute this properly:

```
cars(type: "Sports Car") {
  name
  year
}
```

Is what I'm trying to do even possible?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is possible. Could you post your types please?

Comment: this just depends on how you've set up your [schema](http://graphql.org/learn/schema/#arguments)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have your resolver for *cars* set up as a sub query of *houses*. The result from the *houses* query should be passed as the *root* argument to the *cars* sub query.

```
type House {
  id
  color
  cars( type: String! ): [ Car ]
}

type Car {
  name
  year
}
```

Your resolver might look like:

```
Query: {
  async houses( root, args, context ) {
    return { ... houses ... }
  }
},
houses: {
  async cars( root, args, context ) {
    return { ... cars ... }
  }
}
```

Then create a resolver for *cars* that is nested underneath the *houses* query. Here's an article on it if you are using graphql-tools from Apollo: [Writing resolvers with graphql-tools](http://dev.apollodata.com/tools/graphql-tools/resolvers.html)

Hope this helps!